# Can I factor in the sum of a projector?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, summation, tensor-products, kronecker-product

If $P_j$ is a projector of the form $P_j=I_X\otimes \left|j\right>\left<j\right|$ then given $\left|x\right>\in X$ and operator $A_i: X\rightarrow X$ [is it true that](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/361562/2540), for if $\{\left|i\right>\}$ forming an orthonormal basis

$$\sum_{j}P_{j}\sum_{i}A_i\left|x\right>\left|i\right>=\sum_{i}P_iA_i\left|x\right>\left|i\right>$$

---

I've convinced myself of this with

$$\begin{aligned}
\sum_{j}P_{j}\sum_{i}A_i\left|x\right>\left|i\right>&=\sum_{j,i}P_{j}A_i\left|x\right>\left|i\right>\\
&=\sum_{j,i}\left(I_X\otimes \left|j\right>\left<j\right|\right)A_i\left|x\right>\left|i\right>\\
&=\sum_{j,i}\left(I_XA_i\left|x\right>\right)\otimes \left|j\right>\left<j\right|\left|i\right>\\
&=\sum_{j=i}A_i\left|x\right>\otimes \left<j\vert i\right>\left|j\right>+\sum_{j\neq i}A_i\left|x\right>\otimes \left<j\vert i\right>\left|j\right>\\
&=\sum_{j=i}A_i\left|x\right>\otimes \left<j\vert i\right>\left|j\right>\\
&=\sum_{i}A_i\left|x\right>\otimes \left<i\vert i\right>\left|i\right>\\
&=\sum_{i}\left(I_XA_i\left|x\right>\right)\otimes \left|i\right>\left<i\right|\left|i\right>\\
&=\sum_{i}\left(I_X\otimes \left|i\right>\left<i\right|\right)A_i\left|x\right>\left|i\right>\\
&=\sum_{i}P_{i}A_i\left|x\right>\left|i\right>\,\square\\
 \end{aligned}$$

but I'm not that proficient at matrix operations or summation tricks and fear I may have done violence ot both.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, if $x\in X$ and if $|x\rangle\,|i\rangle$ means $|x\rangle  \otimes |i\rangle$, then your computation is correct.

Comment: Yes $\left|x\right>\in X$ (not $\left|j\right>$). Fixed.